# facebook api post to wall

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, post

I currently am able to post to a users wall however I would like the post to give a preview since what im posting is a link...

To explain myself better If i was to log into my facebook account and copy a link and paste it to my wall it displays an audio player (all the meta data is already configured, tested and working) however, using code to post this same link it doesnt show the audio player instead it only shows the link to click on. Is there a way i can make facebook display the audio player...?

Heres the code im using to post:

```
$fbResult = $facebook->api( 
    '/' . $userId . '/feed/', 
    'post', 
    array('access_token' => $access_token, 'message' => $url) 
);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming you’re posting the URL as part of your `message` parameter?

Do it by explicitly using the `link` parameter for the URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links