# Facebook API daily post from PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, post

I'm working on a problem for many days now without solution.

**What I got :**

- A MySQL database with 1000+ advices
- A daily advice displayed on a page with a PHP script
- A FB Application + FB SDK
- A FB user account

**What I'm looking for :**

- A daily post from my FB account containing the daily advice

**The best result I got so far :**

- A php page which post the daily advice by clicking on a button then login in FB.

Is it possible to save the login informations in the PHP script to get a fully automatic daily post with cron ?

Does anyone know a solution ?

Sincerly,

Comment: have a look at the follow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973091/facebook-api-post-to-wall, it has documentation for PHP post to facebook, so you can write the script to include that code and then call the script via cron. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank's but I already use this doc. I'm able to launch a cron task on this script but the "robot" can't login into FB : that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok folks, **I did it**.

Here is my solution :

**1) Download the Facebook PHP SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk**

**2) Generate an extended access token with this code (generate_token.php) :**

```
  require_once('src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'YOUR APP ID',
            'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET ID',
            'fileUpload' => true
        ));     

  $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
  $access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".$fb_appId."_access_token"];

  $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

  $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

The $accessToken is a 60 days long access to your account by the application.

Store this token in your database.

**3) Publish script (fb_post.php):**

Get the $accessToken from your database, then use it to access to your account without manuel login :

`require_once('src/facebook.php');`

```
$app_id         = 'YOUR APP ID';
$app_secret     = 'YOUR APP SECRET ID';

$config = array(
'appId' =>  $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
);


$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->setAccessToken($fbAccessToken);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Use the first page (generate_token.php) once every 2 months to generate a 60 days token.

"Et voila", just configure a daily Cron Job which execute "fb_post.php" and your robotic Facebook will rise !

Answer (score 1):

did you try facebook SDK for PHP, it is simple you have to register your app with facebook and use your application id and application secret following link contains a sample script.

developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi

Comment: I'm currently using the Facebook SDK (added to the original post) but a login is asked in order to make the App posting from the PHP.

I'm looking for an automatic post, without login myself but by the PHP.

Comment: once i used posting to FB wall before they used graph api, now i am using networkedblogs's , i pass them RSS and they publish it

Answer (score 0):

1.You need your Website to set as an Facebook App

2.read into https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Basicly it is possible of course. But it for me it needs time to get used to the Graph Api.

means a quick answer for your desire is not possible

Comment: So I should drop the FB API and use Open Graph instead ?

Comment: you can still use FB.api() which generally communicate with the Facebook Open Graph... u also can use the features with PHP via curl or http request.

Comment: Yes it is ... ! I'm gonna try the curl way.